# Cisco asa5505 not up for "certain type of ip-address"

Tags: ip, switch, cisco-asa

Only heard this second hand but we've had a failure in our internet connection in the building. There may have been an upgrade while dealing with the issue.

Everything's back to normal except for a small network behind a Cisco asa5505. Bypassing the switch works so the technician advised us to get a new switch since it was probable that the cisco switch "doesn't support the type of ip-address used".

Does that sound like qualified bullshit to you? It does to me.

Will attempt to sort it out but for the moment I can't get a hold of the user credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless he's talking about IPv6, which I doubt, I suspect he's trying to sell you a new switch, and he'll take a kickback from the sale.   Definitely smells like bullshit.

I suspect what might have happened is the Default Gateway moved, and somebody needs to log into the 5505 and poke it in the right direction.

Comment: Yep. No problem there, what so ever, if you had half a brain.